# How to keep rotated banner text vertically centred, despite length of string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

As part of a project, I need to have a banner/strip of text over the corner of our images, only showing as much of the container as there is text (give or take a bit of padding). But the length of the string varies, which means the means I can't simply use top/left as you usually would.

This picture shows the desired end goal:

[image]

Here is the core HTML/CSS but I can't figure out how to make this responsive in the way it needs to be? Is there a CSS solution or is probably JS with math?

```
<div class="image">
    <img src="image.jpg">
    <div class="banner">
        <span class="banner-text">Banner Text</span>
    </div>
</div>

<style>
.image {
  position:relative;
}

.banner {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try to move down the text before rotation taking into account its length using the way vertical padding is calculated when percentage is used.

here is a few example : (see comment in css)

```css
figure {position:relative;
overflow:hidden;}
figcaption {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  padding:0.5em 3em 0.5em 2em;/* tune padding here*/
  background:linear-gradient(to top, green 2.25em, transparent 2.25em);/* draw only one line average background*/
  transform:rotate(-45deg);
  transform-origin:bottom left;
  box-sizing:border-box;/* include padding and border*/
  min-width:150px;/* tune this to have a minimal width and way down*/
}
/* push me down */
figcaption:before {
  content:'';
  display:inline-block;
  padding-top:90%/*  90% of my parent's width which i figcaption*/
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/300x128">
  <figcaption>caption </figcaption>
</figure>
<figure>
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/300x128">
  <figcaption>caption text</figcaption>
</figure>
<figure>
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/300x128">
  <figcaption>longer caption text</figcaption>
</figure>
<figure>
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/300x128">
  <figcaption>bit longer caption text</figcaption>
</figure>
<figure>
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/300x300">
  <figcaption>tiny bit longer caption text</figcaption>
</figure>
```

here is an animated demo to show the padding effect in action , for ribbons on the left and on the right side

```css
figure {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
margin:0;
}

.left figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  padding: 0.5em 3em 0.5em 2em;
  /* tune padding here*/
  background: linear-gradient( to top, green 2.2em, transparent 2.25em);
  /* draw only one line average background*/
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform-origin: bottom left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* include padding and border*/
  min-width: 150px;
  /* tune this to have a minimal width and way down*/
  /* animation for demo */
  animation: txtin 2s steps(4) alternate infinite;
  word-spacing: 2em;
  color: white
}


/* push me down */

.left figcaption:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 94%;
  /*  90% of my parent's width which i figcaption*/
}

.right figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  top: -3.5em;
  right: -6em;
  padding: 0.5em 4em;
  /* tune padding here*/
  background: green;
  /* draw only one line average background*/
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin: bottom left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* include padding and border*/
  min-width: 12.5em;
  /* tune this to have a minimal width and way down*/
  overflow: hidden;
  /* demo */
  animation: txtin 2s steps(4) alternate infinite;
  word-spacing: 2em;
  color: white
}

@keyframes txtin {
  to {
    text-indent: -21em;
    color: yellow
  }
}
```

```html
<figure class="right">
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/300x300/0af/&text=right_ribbon_of_any_length">
  <figcaption>ribbon animated demo</figcaption>
</figure>
<figure class="left">
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/300x300/0df/&text=left_ribbon_of_any_length">
  <figcaption>ribbon animated demo</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: Genius solution! Yes, perfect. I think it's the rotation that was throwing me; circumventing that immediately resolves the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

After a little bit of digging I found the following solution.

```css
.parent {
  overflow: hidden;
  /* required */
  width: 50%;
  /* for demo only */
  height: 250px/* some non-zero number */
  ;
  margin: 25px auto;
  /* for demo only */
  border: 1px solid grey;
  /* for demo only */
  position: relative;
  /* required  for demo*/
}

.ribbon {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: rebeccapurple;
  color: white;
  padding: 1em 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateX(30%) translateY(0%) rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin: top left;
}

.ribbon:before,
.ribbon:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0 -1px;
  /* tweak */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rebeccapurple;
}

.ribbon:before {
  right: 100%;
}

.ribbon:after {
  left: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <h4 class="ribbon"> Hello Special</h4>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <h4 class="ribbon">Very Special Sale Today</h4>
</div>
```